# Can I run a router with a lower voltage power adapter?

Tags: router, power-supply, voltage

The power adapter for my Linksys WRT54GL v1.1 router died - its output was 10V, 1000mA.

I've tried using a replacement adapter (7.5V, 1000mA) and so far it works. Is this situation stable, or should I buy a proper power adapter for the router?

Comment: FWIW, you can find these routers (and their power supply) at thrift stores and craig's list pretty cheap.  Also Radio Shack sells universal power supplies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OH MY GOD!!! Your not running your router UNDER VOLTAGE!!! If it doesn't burn your house down the router will be forced to run at a lower security level, spawning an internet virus ...

Oops. Sorry got a bit carried away there. Really, it's fine. As previously noted it probably uses a voltage regulator and runs off a lower voltage internally. The only likely problem is instability. If it's not crashing then it's good. BTW if you check the datasheet for this router it's voltage spec is actually 12VDC 1A so you were already under-volting it with the old power supply.

Answer (score 0):

no. do not EVER do that. It will damage your router - they are designed to run at specific voltages, and devices such as routers don't have the best voltage regulation circuitry. In addition, 1000A current seems a little overkill.

Get the correct sort of adaptor, or else if something goes boom, and the magic smoke escapes, you have no one to blame but yourself

Comment: I have found http://kioan.users.uth.gr/wireless/wrt54g/supply.html where similar router has no problem with different ranges of voltage; but i'm not sure how my model will behave.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that it'll work fine, especially if you are already using it without error.  Really it depends on the device and how its setup.  It's designed to convert the input voltage to say 5v before it uses it anyway, it won't matter much.  If it needs 10v to make a specific thing work right, it will.

I wonder if that 1000A vs 1000mA is a labeling error.

Comment: spelling error; fixed that.